# Xamarin image invalid path

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Error is showing

> invalid resource directory name:
>   C:\Users\In\source\repos\Xamarin\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android\obj\Debug\81\res
>   contact.png "res contact.png".

Although I delete this image file from this path and Bild solution
This image is already appear in this path and cant run

How can I do :C

Comment: you need to remove it from the Resources folder in your project

Comment: Oh, I forget.Thanks,it works :D